# Canonical way to search type definitions in typescript 2.0

Tags: typescript, npm, typescript2.0

Since typescript 2.0 instead of typings we are [supposed to use](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/) `npm install @types/<package-name>`.

In typings we have `typings search` command for package lookups.
My question is - what is the canonical way to search type definitions in @types?

So, to clarify, till now the workflow was:

1. `typings search <package-name>`
2. `typings install [--global] <package-name>`

Now:

1. ***Question is about this step***
2. `npm install --save-dev @types/<package-name>`

Comment: That's a really good question, seems npm UI (and probably API as well) has real troubles with `@types` and `@angular`. So I would consider it a bug really.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is possible with console, but Microsoft has provided this tool [online](http://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/) to do that. You can find more details in this [post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/).

I guess the idea is that all the names are maintained after `@types/`. So if the npm package name is `my-test-package`, then you should have `@types/my-test-package` if it exists at all and name can be used.

Unfortunately it seems that the NPM UI itself (and most likely API for the same reson) is rather bad with search for stuff that starts with `@`, so both `@types` and `@angular` does not give you the expected result. I do believe it's a bug and hope it'll be fixed.

Answer (score -1):

The new types are distributed using npm so you can use:

```
$ npm search @types/xxxxx
```

More info at https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/search another option is to use the web search UI http://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/

Comment: this answer is wrong :( just try to search anything, say, npm search @types/abs (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/abs)

Comment: `npm search @types abs` does work fairly well. But it only seems to guarantee that all the keywords are present, not in what order. Also many symbols seems to be ignored completely, including dots and dashes.