# @angular version is shown as unavailable

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015

While I am trying to get/see the all available versions of "@angular"'s package, why it is displaying as "unavailable", highlighted in "RED"

While rest other showing versions, highlighted in "GREEN".

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experienced the same thing, and considering the fact the search in the [NPM UI](https://www.npmjs.com) does not properly work either, I consider it's just a bug and that it does not like `@` symbol (or maybe `/` or both together). `@angular`, `@types`, all don't work properly in Visual Studio UI and npm search.

This is no more that UI bug though, if you type proper values, they will work.

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40097357/canonical-way-to-search-type-definitions-in-typescript-2-0/40460256#40460256).