# Visual Studio 2015 does not show the latest Angular version

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015, package.json

I'm updating the **package.json** file to add **angular2**. But the latest version that I can choose from the list is 0.1.2. I don't see UNAVAILABLE as described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40564136/angular-version-is-shown-as-unavailable).

How can I get the list of all the latest versions starting from version angular2?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@angular version is shown as unavailable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40564136/angular-version-is-shown-as-unavailable)

Comment: The question that you point out shows UNAVAILABLE. I don't see that happen in my case.